# Calculate total and max value in BigDecimal from object in Map using forEach

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map of objects that look like this:

`KEY[string]: id
VALUE[object]: Stock`

Stock object has a `price` attribute that is a BigDecimal.

I want to iterate through this map and find a) the sum b) max stock price.

I want to use Java 8  streams API to increase performance so I tried the following:

```
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> sum = new AtomicReference<>(new BigDecimal(0));
myMap.forEach( (id, Stock) -> {
   sum.updateAndGet(v -> v.add(Stock.getPrice()));
})
```

Is this the correct way to total BigDecimal using forEach? And how can I do the same to find the max stock price in the map?

Comment: No! Use a `reduce` operation. This is definitely not the correct way. If you’re using advanced concurrency constructs to work around the effectively final requirement, you are definitely not doing things correctly!

Comment: If you don't care about loss of precision you could do `myMap.values().stream().map(String::getPrice).mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue).summaryStatistics()`. See [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider the existing question that you linked; does it use a reduce operation?

Comment: Because it uses a mutable container to collect the summary statistics - you asked for `sum` _and_ `max` - it uses a custom `Collector`. If you only wanted one or the other, a `reduce` would make sense because `BigDecimal` is immutable.

Comment: @BoristheSpider while List has a method named `stream` this is not available for Map. Any suggestion? (this is in relation to the question you linked)

Comment: Look at my example above.

Comment: Missed it, thanks!